# View Not Updating For Base Class Change

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 4.  I have a base class that has a protected variable that is not changing in the view when it is toggled.  What needs to be done in order for it to propagate the event?

Here is my base class:

```
export class MyBaseComponent {
    protected showCDNumbers: boolean = false;

    toggleCDNumberVisibility() {
        this.showCDNumbers = !this.showCDNumbers;
    }
}
```

Here is the class that inherits from the base:

```
export class MyComponent extends MyBaseComponent {

}
```

Here is the view:

```
<div>{{showCDNumbers}}</div>
<a (click)="toggleCDNumberVisibility()">Toggle</a>
```

Comment: Could you please add the code snippets showing your calling of the `toggleCDNumberVisibility()` method as well (in the template), or have you not put it in there?

Comment: I added the toggle event. It is working, it does call it.  I put in a console.log there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to see if the view changes upon `toggleCDNumberVisibility()` method call. Inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` from the `@angular/core` library to both classes (parent and child) through their `constructor` and make use of its `detectChanges()` method like this.

> BaseComponent

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

protected showCDNumbers: boolean = false;

constructor (protected ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

toggleCDNumberVisibility() {
 this.showCDNumbers = !this.showCDNumbers;
 this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

> ChildComponent

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

constructor (protected ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
 super(ref);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different version:

```
export class MyBaseComponent {
    protected showCDNumbers: boolean = false;
  constructor(value){
    this.showCDNumbers=value;
  }

    toggleCDNumberVisibility() {
        this.showCDNumbers = !this.showCDNumbers;
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent extends MyBaseComponent{
  name = 'Angular 4';
   constructor(){
     super(true);
   }
    toggleCDNumberVisibility() {
      super.toggleCDNumberVisibility();
    }

}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14un1e?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)